# What happens to a Linked account in Alexa when user password is changed on that account?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I was recently trying out the account linking using Alexa. I understand the Auth code and implicit code. But my scenario is

1) User links account successfully through Alexa app.

2) Now User changes password on the original account.

> What would happen to the linked account ? Would it still be linked ?
>   How would we handle it in our API?  Would the access token not work
>   and we will be able to know ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you implemented the authentication for the skill on your server.  When they link their account you provide a token back to Amazon.  If when the user changes their password you invalidate that token, then the account would no longer be linked.

Comment: Handle in the API and check for invalidated token and send the account linking card again. Makes sense. Thanks